# How to redirect to post if search results only returns one post

Tags: functions, templates, search

I want to send visitors to my search.php after a search to display list of posts. If there is only one search result, user can directlyto the post in question(something like GOOGLE's I am Feeling Lucky Button)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this snippet to your functions.php

```
function redirect_the_single_post() {
    if (is_search() && is_main_query()) {
        global $wp_query;
        if ($wp_query->post_count == 1 && $wp_query->max_num_pages == 1) {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $wp_query->posts['0']->ID ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
} 
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_the_single_post' );
```

hope this will help you!!

Comment: +1 for this. You could/should, however, also check if this is the main query, so I would change the first line to this: `if (is_search() && is_main_query()) {`. And the permalink can also be generated from `$GLOBALS['post']->ID` - but that is not so much shorter. ;) But it is about retrieving a property of an element of an array. Your code is about retrieving a property of an element of an array, which is a property of another object.

Comment: @AbhishekKaushik, take the point and *add it* to the Answer. People will be copy/pasting your snippet for years to come, better improve it, no? ;)